# How Can I define machine when I try to add units on JUJU web interface?

Tags: juju

Here is the situation:

1. I have my charm deployed using Juju and MAAS.
2. When I try to add units using the GUI for the same charm the machine incrementally goes from machine #1 to machine number #n (n is number of units added)
3. Where can I force Juju to run my units on particular machine or same machine as first unit?
4. I know one solution is using the cli with `juju add-unit your-charm-name --to <machine-number>`. But I need it for Juju GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.2.0 of the Juju GUI there is now a Machine View which allows you to create machines and containers as well as manually place units on any machine in your environment without having to go to the CLI.